# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 1 of 4)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1909 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are four entries.

Here is the first  one:

[image]

So far I have come up with this:

> El 29 de Julio emprendió la **marcha** para **Barcelona** con **objeto** de
> **prestar** el servicio de **concentración** por orden de xxx el Director General
> del Cuerpo **en telegrama** **fecha** 27 del **expresado** mes.

Thank you in advance for you help in transcribing this document.

---

#### Update 1

I have updated the text to include @SergioVelasquez suggestions and I adjusted **en telegrama**.

#### Update 2

Added the word **expresado** and updated the translation.

---

#### Translation

> On 29th July, he set off for Barcelona in order to provide the
> concentration service by order of xxx the Director General of the
> Corps in a telegram dated 27th of the same month.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 2 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39419/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 3 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39422/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 4 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39425/28260)

Comment: El 29 de Julio emprendió la **marcha** para **Barcelona** con objeto de **prestar** el servicio de **concentración** por orden de **??** el Director General del Cuerpo **??**. Fecha 27 del **??** mes.

Comment: @SergioVelasquez Thanks for the suggestion. If it is correct then I wonder what "concentration service" really meant? 

Comment: @SergioVelasquez, **en telegrama** would fit.

Comment: *servicio de concentración militar*, where *militar* is inferred from the context of the transcripts. Military / Force concentration.

Comment: I'm not sure about entelegrama or en telegrama. That doesn't make much sense to me, but that's old Spanish, and I'm also not familiar with that.

Comment: @SergioVelasquez I see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_concentration. But since my Great Grandfather is now in the 2nd class of the Civil Guard at this time I didn't expect him to do military activities as such. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SergioVelasquez The last bit could be: *Fecha 27 del **expresado** mes*. That would make sense.

Comment: I'm late this time. The missing word probably is an adjective to show respect for the role, something like Ilmo (Ilustrisimo) o Exmo (Excelentisimo). According to this site https://www.cope.es/actualidad/sociedad/noticias/cual-forma-correcta-dirigirse-los-altos-cargos-20180621_229933, the second one is currently the recommended. On the other hand, I think that your titles are descriptive enough, no need of changing that part, in my opinion.

Comment: @RubioRic Sure. Interrestingly, the second letter to that word looks like a capital E because it looks virtually the same at the first letter E in the text. But I won't worry about it. Do you agree with the transcribed words **en telegrama**?

Comment: Yes, I do. I agree with the whole transcription.

Comment: The missing word is _S. E._ (_Su Excelencia_ = His Excellency).

Comment: @AndrewTruckle By the way, please, note the dates. There was a violent uprising in Barcelona during the last week of July 1909: the [Tragic Week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragic_Week_(Spain)).

Comment: @gparis Thank you for the clarification about the text and for the historical link which helps me gain more insight about what my Great Grandfather was actually going through.

Comment: @gparis I notice towards the end of that article: "After disturbances in downtown Barcelona, **civil guards** and police fired on demonstrators in Las Ramblas, ..." So there was my Great Grandfather, in that group of Civil Guards.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle It seems your relative was part of the _other army units that were brought in from Valencia, Zaragoza, Pamplona and Burgos..._ that probably arrived at Barcelona some days after the beginning of the uprising...

Comment: @gparis Perhaps. Although I assumed that my Great Grandfather was still posted at Herrara, Seville, when he was called up for this. Does Seville fall under one of those locations?

Comment: Notice that Pamplona and Burgos are not mentioned at all in the Spanish version of the article. In such version, Valencia and Zaragoza appear as the first sources of military reinforcements but that not excludes other units coming from different parts of Spain like Seville. Also, your ancestor's home town is Herrera with two e ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on further reading of the original text, and suggestions by @SergioVelasquez and @gparis in the comments, we have settled on the following transcription:

> El 29 de Julio emprendió la marcha para Barcelona con objeto de
> prestar el servicio de concentración por orden de S. E. el Director
> General del Cuerpo en telegrama fecha 27 del expresado mes.

And, we have agreed on the following translation:

> On 29th July, he set off for Barcelona in order to provide the
> concentration service by order of His Excellency the Director General of the
> Corps in a telegram dated 27th of the same month.

---

#### Historical Insights

It is worth mentioning the information that @gparis provided in the comments:

> There was a violent uprising in Barcelona during the last week of July 1909: the [Tragic Week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragic_Week_(Spain)).

Comment: Based on the input from @gparis, you can replace **xxx el Director** with **S.E el Director**

Comment: @SergioVelasquez Thanks for the nudge to do that!