# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 2 of 4)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1909 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are four entries.

Here is the second one:

[image]

The transcribed text so far:

> El Excmo. Señor Director General del Cuerpo en común no. 197 de 29 de
> Agosto xxx por el Señor Coronel Subinspector del xxx en 29 del mismo
> manifiesta se haga cortar en la filiación de este individuo la xxx
> cougue Rio visto el comportamiento el servado enxxx servicios a las
> xxx del Excmo. Sr. Cafistan  General de la 4a Región continuo de las
> acouteemiento de xxx en Barcelona.
>
> El 2º Jefe

Thank you in advance for you help in transcribing this document.

---

#### Translation

Using the transcribed text provided in the answers below we get the following translation:

> His Excellency the Director General of the Corps, in communication no.
> 197 of 29th August, sent by the Colonel Sub-Inspector of the Third on
> the 29th of the same month, states that this individual's affiliation
> should include the satisfaction with which he has seen the behaviour
> observed in all the services he has been involved in under the orders
> of His Excellency the Captain General of the 4th Region on the
> occasion of the events that took place in Barcelona.
>
> The 2nd Chief

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)
Can the translation be improved at all? I wonder what the events were that took place in Barcelona back then? I guess we will never know. :)

---

#### Translation Update 1

Translation updated to include the suggestions provided by @RubioRic.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 1 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39416/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 3 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39422/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 4 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39425/28260)

Comment: Well, August 1909 wasn't a good time to be in Barcelona precisely. Your ancestor lived "interesting" times https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragic_Week_(Spain)

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks. I see the same link provided a few moments ago by 'gparis' as a comment to the first note for 1909.

Comment: I didn't see that comment. Sorry for the repetition. I didn't think about the date and the place until you mentioned it in this post.

Comment: @RubioRic Nor me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El Excmo. Señor Director General del Cuerpo en común no. 197 de 29 de Agosto **trasladada** por el Señor Coronel Subinspector del **Reino (?)** en 29 del mismo manifiesta se haga cortar en la filiación de este individuo la **satisfacción** **con que** **ha** visto el comportamiento **observado** en **cuantos** servicios **intervino** a las **órdenes** del Excmo. Sr. **Capitán** General de la 4a Región **con motivo** de **los acontecimientos desarrollados** en Barcelona.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the transcription is almost done in Paribus' answer but

> El Excmo. Señor Director General del Cuerpo en **comon** (**comunicación**) no. 197 de 29 de
> Agosto trasladado por el Señor Coronel Subinspector del **Tercio** en 29 del mismo
> manifiesta se haga **constar** en la filiación de este individuo la satisfacción
> con que ha visto el comportamiento observado en cuantos servicios intervino  a las órdenes del Excmo. Sr. Capitán General de la 4a Región con motivo de los acontecimientos desarrollados en Barcelona.
>
> El 2º Jefe

By the way, August 1909 wasn't a good time to be in Barcelona. More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragic_Week_(Spain)).

Comment: _comon_ (with a mark above the word) should be an abbreviation of _comunicación_ (communication).

Comment: @gparis I think that you're right