# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 3 of 4)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1909 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are four entries.

Here is the third one:

[image]

The transcribed text so far:

> 1909: Por Real orden fecha 10 de agosto (D. O. no 177) se decir las
> gracias a este individuo por haber contendiendo a la xxx de xxx xxx
> xxx a Canfórica.
>
> El 2º Jefe

To be honest, I am not sure if the abbreviate is **D.O.** I have located [D. O. no. 177](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=8386) but don't know what I am looking for. I did wonder if the abbreciation was **R.O.** but it does look like **D.O.** to me.

---

#### Bulletin Update

I realise that it must be related to the main article on  pages 1 and 2 with the title **Real Ordenes**. I seeit is dated 10 Agosto. As to what it says ... another matter. :)

---

#### Translation

Using the transcribed text provided in the comments by @gparis below we get the following translation:

> By Royal Order dated 10 August (D. O. No. 177) this individual was
> thanked for having contributed to the mobilisation of troops for the
> Campaign (?).
>
> The 2nd Chief

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 1 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39416/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 2 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39419/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 4 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39425/28260)

Comment: Por Real orden fecha 10 de agosto (D. O. no 177) se **dan** las gracias a este individuo por haber **contribuido** a la **movilización** de **tropas con destino** a **Campaña?**. _Campaña_ may refer to the [Second Melillan campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Melillan_campaign). As you said, the main article of the D.O. no. 177 is an order to thank all the individuals involved in the organization of this troop movement and the repression of the protests.

Comment: By the way, the same article mentions that the additional troop movement to Barcelona involved forces from Mahon, Valencia, Zaragoza, Pamplona, Burgos, Madrid and Sevilla.

Comment: Thanks @gparis. I have added an initial translation based on your suggestions to my question. I think you are correct about the last word being Campaña. It makes sense and would fit the context given the related information in the linked bulletin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions by @gparisin the comments, we have settled on the following transcription:

> Por Real orden fecha 10 de agosto (D. O. no 177) se dan las gracias a
> este individuo por haber contribuido a la movilización de tropas con
> destino a Campaña (?).

And, we have agreed on the following translation:

> By Royal Order dated 10 August (D. O. No. 177) this individual was
> thanked for having contributed to the mobilisation of troops for the
> Campaign (?).

---

### Historial Insights

It is worth mentioning the information that @gparis provided in the comments:

> *Campaña* may refer to the [Second Melillan campaign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Melillan_campaign). As you said, the
> main article of the D.O. no. 177 is an order to thank all the
> individuals involved in the organization of this troop movement and
> the repression of the protests.
>
> The same article mentions that the additional troop movement to
> Barcelona involved forces from Mahon, Valencia, Zaragoza, Pamplona,
> Burgos, Madrid and Sevilla.