# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 4 of 4)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1909 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records there are four entries.

Here is the fourth and final one (I'll start on 1910 tomorrow! :) ):

[image]

The transcribed text so far:

> 1909: El 8 de Diciembre repredo de Barcelona desde protesta el
> servicio de concentración, **incorporándose** al puesto de Herrera desde finió el
> año.

I think the fist unknown word spans the *two lines*.

---

#### Update

I had another attempt and think I worked out the missing word (shown in **bold**).

---

#### Translation

At the moment I have this translation:

> On 8th December he returned from Barcelona to protest the
> concentration service, joining the Herrera post at the end of the
> year.

But in English I don't think it is 100% correct as it is. The phrasing needs changing relative to the word **protest** I think.

Assuming my transcribed efforts is correct, what is the most approopriate translation? Thank you in advance.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 1 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39416/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 2 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39419/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1909 (note 3 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39422/28260)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1909: El 8 de Diciembre **regresó** de Barcelona **donde** **prestaba** el servicio de concentración, incorporándose al puesto de Herrera **donde** finió el año.

Note in particular the small accent very far away from the "o" in *regresó*, which is as small as the accents on *concentración* or *finió*. The collocation "prestar el servicio" appears also in [note 1 of 4](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39416/transcribing-spanish-civil-guard-notes-for-1909-note-1-of-4).

My translation would be

- 1909: On 8th December he returned from Barcelona, where he was providing the concentration service, and joined the Herrera post until the end of the year.

The use of the gerund in "incorporándose" is a (now incorrect) *[gerundio de posterioridad](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/el-gerundio-con-valor-de-posterioridad-es-incorrecto-825/)*, i.e., it just means that one action (*incorporarse*) happened after the other (*regresar*).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I had to look up **gerund** to see what it meant. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just a side note about the word **finó/finió**.

There are two similar verbs in Spanish: finar and finir.

According to the DLE:

> [**finar**](https://dle.rae.es/finar) (finó)
>
> 1. intr. Fallecer, morir. Era u. t. c. prnl.
> 2. prnl. Consumirse, deshacerse por algo o apetecerlo con ansia.
>
> [**finir**](https://dle.rae.es/finir) (finió)
>
> 1. intr. desus. Finalizar, acabar. U. en Col.

The first one means to **die** (or to crave, in its second nuance) and the second one corresponds to **finish**.
By the context we can assume that the verb that appears in the document is **finir**,
that it's not used currently (**desus.**).

---

About your last translation: ***serving** in the concentration **service*** looks a bit redundant to me. Such redundancy is not present in the original text. That's the reason for @wimi's suggestion: **providing** the concentration service.

We don't know exactly what's a concentration service but taking into account what we know about the context, probably we are talking about **crowd-control**.

> Crowd control is a public security practice where large crowds are
> managed to prevent the outbreak of crowd crushes, affray, fights
> involving drunk and disorderly people or riots.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowd_control)

A good alternative in my opinion may be:

> he served in crowd-control duties

> he served (prestaba el servicio) in crowd-control duties (de concentración).

The verb tense in the original text is simple past (prestaba servicio/served) and not past continuous (estaba prestando servicio/was serving).

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation about those terms and I think it makes it clear the correct word is **finió**. I reverted my text in my document and added **(crowd-control duties)** in parenthesis.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @wimi. Only the word "finió", I undertand it as "finó" meaning something like "finished"

- El 8 de Diciembre regresó de Barcelona donde prestaba el servicio de
  concentración, incor- porandose al puesto de Herrera donde **finó**
  el año

And could be something like:

- On December 8th he returned from Barcelona where he rendered the
  concentration service, incor- porating Herrera's post where he
  finished the year.

Comment: I think you might be right about that. I have made that change. I am going to add a third answer just for clarity about my final text I am using. Note that I have just glanced over the 3 notes for 1910 and I can see he was still serving at **Herrera**.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle if he was still alive in 1910, that's an argument for *finió* (from *finir*, "to finish") over *finó* (from *finar*, "to die") ;)

Comment: He did not die until 1965. So go with your text.